# SQL Server Login Failed (18542)

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I recently had to get someone from IT Support at work to install SQL Server 2022 Developer Edition on my laptop because I do not have admin rights to install software.

We chose Basic installation as the default and everything went through fine.

I tried to log in using Windows authentication and it gives me the 18542 login failed error.

I suspect that perhaps because an administrator account was used to install it my own AD login account does not exist on the local server?

What is the best solution going forward? Do I need to call the IT support to connect to the local instance and create an account for me on my local instance? Would I be able to use Windows Authentication to login to this instance?

Thanks

Comment: yes, he/she/chatgpt should've given you a way to login, probably he forgot. It's easiest to give your windows login rights to access the server,but sql server login is also possible. Also, don't forget to actually received  rights so you can do stuff, not just login :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to select Mix Mode authentication during the install and add your windows user for you to be able to login with windows credentials. You set up a password during the installation process so it might be worth checking with IT personnel to get a hold of the default user’s (sa) password. In addition, It is worth checking the SQL Server authentication mode. You need to make sure SQL Server and Windows authentication mode is selected. The steps are outlined in this article.
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/01/17/sql-server-fix-login-failed-for-user-username-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection-microsoft-sql-server-error-18452/